# Freeeze few lines and top row for an HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have header line on my page and then I have a table displayed on the page. I want that header line and top row of the table to be freezed and rest the of the table to be scrollable. My table is without `<THEAD>` element and also I tried using positon:fixed to freeze the header line and top row of table but only top row is fixed. How can I freeze header line as well?
TIA

Code:

`<div id="topheader">`

```
<h1> This is header line </h1>
</div>
<table ellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="1" width="100%" STYLE="empty-cells:show; position:fixed; top:300px;" id="reporttable" >
<tr class="header">
<td align="left">
  Field1
</td>
<td align="left">
   Field2
</td>
<td align="left">
   Field3
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="1" width="100%" STYLE="empty-cells:show;" id="reporttables">
<tr class="tbody" >
<td>
  Data1
</td>
<td>
 Data2
</td>
<td>
 Data3
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

    div.topheader{
        position:fixed;
        top:200px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: post a minimal example code so that we could help. also would you allow a javascript solution as well?

Comment: Can you read about DataTable. I guess it might helps you https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html.

Comment: @Abhinav : I am open for javascript solutions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot do this with just one table element.

A good way to approach this is to create 2 tables and use the `table-layout: fixed` property on the tables and then set a fixed width on `td` and `th`.

Check this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5fq6Lvf6/) or the code snippet below.

```css
div.div-demo {
  height: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table.demo {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table.demo td, th {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="demo">
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="div-demo">
  <table class="demo">
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Chris but I am not using TH element in my code. will this code work with TD element?

Comment: now the problem is that I have more Table and Div elements on my page and above CSS applies for all which I don't want. Is there any other way to apply it to particular table and div?

Comment: Yes, give the affected table or divs a class, then add that to your css. For example in html: `<table class="demo">` and in your css `table.demo {...`

Comment: I modified the code above. Let me know if this helped you at all.